# Multiple function in one Ready Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#btn1").click(function() {
            $(".show_div").slideToggle('fast');
        });
});
```

and another function

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#btn2").click(function() {
            $(".show_div").slideToggle('fast');
        });
});
```

how can i merge this function so if the `btn1` is clicked it will perform the slidetoogle, and if the `bn2` is clicked it will perform the slidetoogle too?
thank you!

Comment: You can add both the methods one below another in the ready function. It will work fine.

Comment: On your example, the two buttons will slide the same div, is this really what you need ? If not, it's probably better to get this system working with html anchors. See this example : http://lab.infographizm.com/jquery/spoilers-simples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can separate selectors by using `,`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1, #btn2").click(function() {
        $(".show_div").slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define several functions under you `document.ready` function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $(".show_div").slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $(".show_div").slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $("#anyId").click(function() {
        //whatever
    });

});
```

Comment: this is working but after adding this code `$("#btn_0").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#divider").offset().top
     }, 500);` this is not working. what happen?

Comment: Ahh! i found my problem, i just forget to add this `});` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add your all element id inside $() , just like

```html
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#btn1, #btn2").click(function() {
            $(".show_div").slideToggle('fast');
        });
});
```